# Android Studio missing essential plugin org.jetbrains.android for MAC ERROR

Tags: android, jetbrains-ide, android-studio-2.3

[image]

I've read all the posts for mac on StackOverflow. Like this...

> On Mac OS
> Open /Users//Library/Preferences/AndroidStudio4.0/codestyles
> delete disabled_plugins.txt
> restart Android Studio,

but I don't have a text file named disabled_plugins.txt. What should I do?

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same problem, and this worked for me:
Click on Go then Go to Folder..., will appear to you a small window that asks you to enter the path copy this ( ~/Library/Application Support/Google/) next delete all disabled_plugins.txt lastly Quit Android studio and restart it.

Answer (score 1):

On a mac, open your finder, type disabled_plugins.txt in the search box of your finder.

On my mine, it was located at MYUSERNAME > Library > Application Support > Google > AndroidStudioxx

Then just remove the line that references org.jetbrains.kotlin

By the way, the Library folder in your home user directory is a hidden folder. If you can't see it in your finder, that's the reason why.